# Where can I download iPhone SDK 3.1?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.1

I'm trying to setup Titanium Developer which requires the iphone sdk 3.1+. I can't install 3.2 because I'm running OS X 10.5.6. Where can I download sdk 3.1?

Comment: developer.apple.com has it, you just have to dig for it.

Comment: You also need to register as a developer (free, but you need to give Apple an email)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/development_tools/iphonesdk.html

Comment: That takes me to the 3.1 landing page, but forwards me to the dev registration page when I try to download it (I'm already a registered dev & logged in).